# Trigger a View's onTouchEvent via Code in Android

Tags: android, touch-event

Can someone tell me how to trigger a particular View's onTouchEvent code, through Android code (as opposed to actually touching the device) and feed it with custom MotionEvent data?

Actually, all I really want to modify is the results of the MotionEvent's getX() and getY() ints. All the other functions of the MotionEvent I'd like to copy from another MotionEvent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use 
[dispatchTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29)

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know any of the conditions or purposes of your code I can only give you this:

```
yourView.onTouchEvent(yourModifiedMotionEvent);
```

Which makes the view think it was touched with the yourModifiedMotionEvent event.

Answer (score -1):

Use "**performClick()**" of that view.

i.e `<your view>.performClick();`

this will call its onClick defined.

Hope it solves your problem.